# WebClientResponseException returns with 200 HTTP Status Code when the server is stopped manually

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Currently, I am trying to get messages from the Server-side via WebClient by using Flux.  I want to check if I can handle exceptions for non-2xx HTTP Status cases. During receiving messages I stop the server.
In such a scenario, I expect to get 500 status codes with my customised exception but it returns the 200 status code with my customised exception.

Below you can find the output logs (Bold parts are important)

> 

```
**org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: 200 OK from GET serverUri; nested exception is reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:229) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]**
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:207) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1863) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:334) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxFilterFuseable.java:382) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onError(MonoCollect.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:172) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.subscribe(FluxReceive.java:143) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:340) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onError(FluxConcatMap.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onError(FluxBufferPredicate.java:346) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:553) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:334) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:903) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onError(FluxConcatArray.java:207) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:321) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:686) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onError(FluxFlattenIterable.java:257) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:465) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:260) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:453) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:488) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundClose(HttpClientOperations.java:298) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelInactive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:73) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.channelInactive(HttpContentDecoder.java:235) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:392) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:357) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:326) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET <serverUri> [DefaultClientResponse]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET <serverUri> [DefaultClientResponse]
Original Stack Trace: 2022-05-30 11:06:33.864 ERROR 14499 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.m.c.s.service.MyServiceClass      : Error receiving message.
**com.myProject.MyCustomisedException: The server responded with error [200] when attempting to sending response**
    at com.myProject.MyExceptionHandler……
```

Here's the Client-Side code:

```
webClient
        .get()
        .uri(serverUri)
        .header(headerName, headerValue)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(MyType)
        .onErrorMap(
            WebClientResponseException.class, handleMyException());



messageStream.subscribe(m -> 
{
…
executorService.execute
( **operations with callback function** )
…
}
);
```

What am I missing in such a scenario?

Comment: Could you please provide us with handleMyException() body?

Comment: `public Throwable handleMyException(WebClientResponseException e) 
{
     log.error(…);
     throw new MyCustomisedException(
           format( “Some Exception Message”,
                        getRawStatusCode), e);
}`

Answer (score 2):

What you might be missing is the following: if you're stopping abruptly the server while it's writing the response to the client, this indeed causes an I/O-like exception when the client is reading the response.

But this doesn't change the fact that the server already wrote and sent the HTTP status and response headers to the client. It's not the client's job to decide what the HTTP response should look like. The server indeed responded with HTTP 200 OK but something bad happened while writing the response body.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianClozel! In my case, the root cause was in the type of PrematureClosedException. For this specific case, I modified my exception handling function to throw a different customised exception and for the rest of the case, I am throwing my already existing customised exception which also shows an HTTP status code that returns from the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved, but I want to note the issue I had today.

I indeed had the same error, but in my case that was a server which was returning a `200 - OK` and a chunked response. That response was a file (`byte[]`) and my code was simply not aggregating the received byte arrays.
Since only the first chunk was consumed, the client was throwing the same exception, for I was closing the connection before receiving following chunks.

I was using:

```java
    return WebClient.builder()
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                                                                              .followRedirect(true)))
                    .build()
                    .get()
                    .uri(resourceUrl)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
```

while I should have used something like:

```java
    return WebClient.builder()
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                                                                              .followRedirect(true)))
                    .build()
                    .get()
                    .uri(resourceUrl)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(byte[].class)
                    .reduce(Arrays::concatenate)
```